# SELECT с меняющимися параметрами

Tags: c++

В чем разница?

1-й Вариант:

```
if(mysql_query(&mysql, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='User'") != 0) exiterr(3);
```

2-й вариант:

```
char* login = "User";

if(mysql_query(&mysql, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='",login,"'") != 0) exiterr(3);
```

Первый вариант работает, а второй при компиляции выдает ошибку.

> `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h: In function 'int main()':
> /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h:440: error: too many arguments to function 'int mysql_query(MYSQL*, const char*)'
> /var/www/advert/data/www/advert.kg/src/test.cpp:32: error: at this point in file`

Answer (score 3):

```
 "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='",login,"'"
```

Подобная конкатенация не будет работать!

Используйте класс string

```
#include <string>

std::string login = "User";

if(mysql_query(&mysql, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='" + login + "'") != 0) exiterr(3);
```

Comment: Не получается. При компиляции выдает ошибку.
/var/www/advert/data/www/advert.kg/src/test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/var/www/advert/data/www/advert.kg/src/test.cpp:36: error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' to 'const char*' for argument '2' to 'int mysql_query(MYSQL*, const char*)'

Comment: А так: ..., ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='" + login + "'").c_str())!=0... ?

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.